# Using markup in label text or similar element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_ReadOnlyFld" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=GetGuiLocalString("lbl_ReadOnlyFldDescr")%>
```

I need the text in some element so I can access it:

For example:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_InputFld" runat="server"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lbl_InputFldDescr" runat="server" text='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= GetGuiLocalString("lbl_InputFldDescr")%>'></asp:Label>
```

It just gives me stuff inside ''... any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

<%= is meant to directly output something on the page and can't be used inside other controls.
You should either use <%# and databind the control or set the text in the code behind. Also the other stuff should be inside those tags so it would be:

<asp:Label ID="lbl_InputFldDescr" runat="server" text='<%# "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + GetGuiLocalString("lbl_InputFldDescr")%>' />

and then lbl_InputFldDescr.DataBind(); somewhere in your code behind (provided you don't already databind the page or someting).

Answer (score 0):

ASPX:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_InputFld" runat="server">my name is Jhon</asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_InputFldDescr" runat="server" text='<%# "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + GetGuiLocalString("lbl_InputFldDescr")%>'></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataBind();           
}
public string GetGuiLocalString(string id)
{
        string s = "hello";
        Label lbl = (Label)Form.FindControl(id);
        if(lbl!=null)
        {
            if ( ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(lbl.Text))
                s = lbl.Text;
        }            
        return s;
}
```